# HSQDLDB throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: when encrypted DB is introduced

Tags: java, database, encryption, hsqldb, embedded-database

```
    //java code in netbeans
    //Registering the HSQLDB JDBC driver and getting connection  
 Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:\\Users\\PC\\mydb_fileencr;crypt_key=3f302916463bf54b10f5fc2b810ca43d;crypt_type=AES", "SA", "");

//creation of table
 String sql = "CREATE TABLE PM (id INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, name varchar (500), submission_date date , file blob )";//PRIMARY KEY (id);

//insertion code
String sql = "INSERT INTO PM (name , submission_date , file ) values (?,?,?)";//PRIMARY KEY (id)

//values
pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            String name = "John";
            pstmt.setString(1, name);
            pstmt.setDate(2, getCurrentDate());
            pstmt.setBinaryStream(3, input); //the file is 1.3MB zip file and working fine
            try {
                result = pstmt.executeUpdate();
            } catch (java.sql.SQLException sq) {
                sq.printStackTrace();
            }
//this code works fine within netbeans process when encryption key is not introduced in jdbc url.
//key is obtained by CALL CRYPT_KEY('AES', null); in hsqldb gui

//and the exception is

Connection created successfully
INSERT INTO PM (name , submission_date , file ) values (?,?,?)
java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 528384
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at test.HSQLConnectDB.insert(HSQLConnectDB.java:130)
    at test.HSQLConnectDB.main(HSQLConnectDB.java:168)
query executed 0
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 528384
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.SessionData.allocateLobForResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.allocateResultLob(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.performPreExecute(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 528384
    at org.hsqldb.persist.LobManager.deflate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.LobManager.setBytesBACompressedPart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.LobManager.setBytesBACompressed(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.LobManager.setBytesBA(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.LobManager.setBytes(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.SessionData.allocateBlobSegments(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

Code is written in java using Netbeans. Also i want to ask, if i insert data in hsqldb using file mode:my specified directory and also insert data using hsqldb GUI, then conflict occurs and multiple exceptions are raised but anyways my preference is to check how encryption is applied in hsqldb. please help if some "complete" sample code is available

Comment: ok i got the answer. hsqldb 2.5 and above already encrypts lob files so it does not allow you to again encrypt them. you have to add crypt_lobs=false in dburl as 
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:\\Users\\PC\\mydb_fileencr;crypt_key=3f302916463bf54b10f5fc2b810ca43d;crypt_type=AES;crypt_lobs=false", "SA", "");

Comment: but exception raised as arrayIndexOutOfBoundException is not understandable for this issue...

Answer (score 1):

If you use the latest version 2.5.1 and create a new database, you do not need to use `crypt_lobs=true` in your connection URL (it is done automatically) to encrypt the lob files. The `ArrayindexOutOfBoundsException` was due to a bug that has been finxed in version 2.5.1. If you find any issue, you can report for the HSQLDB project.

The advice given about `crypt_lobs=false` is for databases created using much older versions of HSQLDB and does not apply to new databases. With new databases and the latest versions, you do not need to set this property at all.

Comment: I am using hsqldb-2.5.0.... another issue found is: While creating db in mem mode as dbname.0 = mvdb (in server.properties file) , then setting jdbc url in runManagerSwing:Connect window is hsqldb:hsql:mem:mvdb...then connecting to this url, the java CRUD operations code asks for (same) table e.g "User" creation with every run. (If we don't call "create table user...." with every run, the console throws exception: table/view doesn’t exist),.
Wheras if we call create table user with every run, it overwrites previous output everytime. This also shows that if we insert 1 record, it will remain 1

Comment: Whereas writing new DB in hsqldb:file mode works fine...one time table creation call is enough with conn url as jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/mvdb1 ... and it adds record sequentially as normal way

Comment: Use version 2.5.1 to avoid the ArrayIndex... exception. Re the mem db, you need to start the server and connect to it with jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/mvdb.

Comment: yes file:localhost mode is working fine. i wanted to use mem:mode also but it gives abnormal results. However can you tell me: Is the crypt_key() function the only thing to encrypt hsqldb. Is there any more help on utilization of symmetric cipher and transformation that may be available from the JVM for encryption of hsqldb and the CRUD operations performed on that encypted data afterwards...

Comment: Re the mem db with server: You need to start the server itself with a mem database (dbname.0=mvdb, database.0=mem:db), then connect to it with jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/mvdb if you want to keep the mem data. All the information about crypt_key etc. is in the Guide.